# Interact with Google Chrome on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

From an excel file in VBA, I would like to click on the big button on this webpage (https://www.ilovepdf.com/jpg_to_pdf), select a file from my computer to download to this website (select the right path), validate, download the new file, then close the tab.

I have for the moment manage to open the browser but I can interact with the website..

Thanks for your help :)

```
Sub ConvertFile()


ChromeLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 'Location of Chrome.exe in your PC
MyURL = "https://www.ilovepdf.com/jpg_to_pdf" 'URL that you would like to open; you may also use a variable for this, or a pointer to the location of the URL
Shell (ChromeLocation & " -url " & MyURL)


End Sub
```

Comment: This is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

You could use selenium basic to launch and interact with chrome. I am showing how to launch, enter a search term, and click a button. The rest of your question is simply too broad. The example will bring up the [download site](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) in the search results. After installation you will need to add a reference to selenium type library.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.google.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementById("lst-ib").SendKeys "Selenium basic GitHub"
         .FindElementsByTag("form")(1).FindElementByCss("input[value='Google Search']").Click
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```